# Purging file from Git repo failed, unable to create new backup

Tags: git, git-commit, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I tried to remove a file from my remote repo by running:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' HEAD
```

But Git complains that

> Cannot create new backup. A previous backup already exists in refs/original/
>   Force overwriting the backup with -f
>   rm: cannot remove /.git-rewrite/backup-refs : Permission denied
>   rm: cannot remove directory /.git-rewrite : Directory not empty

This was after I already deleted the .git-rewrite directory on Windows.

How can I remove that file? It's a 29Mb file sitting on my repo, so I quite need to remove the file.

I tried to delete the commit in `git rebase -i`, but apparently because the commit touched a lot of different files, Git complains of conflicts and I aborted to be safe.

Comment: For search engines: this may also apply when your error message is `.git-rewrite already exists, please remove it`.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You have already performed a filter-branch operation. After filter-branch, Git keeps refs to the old commits around, in case something goes wrong.

You can find those in `.git/refs/original/…`. Either delete that directory and all files within, or use the `-f` flag to force Git to delete the old references.

```
git filter-branch -f \
--index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' HEAD
```

Comment: Finally got it to work, thanks! I did try the -f flag, but the problem was I was putting it at the end of the command eg. HEAD -f. Seeing your command made me try putting the flag at the start, and it worked! =D

Comment: option flags (`-f`) go before the refs (`HEAD`). refs go last

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after adding -f AND deleting the directory.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Yaron: which error? `git add` doesn't show up in my answer.

Comment: @knittl, i wasn't referring to `git add`. I was receiving the same error as the original poster even after deleting the `.git/refs/original/` folder and using the `-f` flag in the `git filter-branch` command.  The solution, in my case, was to delete the `.git/packed-refs` file.

Comment: @Yaron: `packed-refs` contains all references. You might have deleted a lot of important references.

Comment: I am getting this same problem with permissions, even I did the `filter-branch` for the *first* time! Any ideas? Repository was actually copied (fetched) from the remote repository.

Comment: @Gabrielius: are the file and directory permissions in your repository correct? Can you write to your disk, is still disk space available? Also make sure the `.git-rewrite` directory does not exist.

Comment: @knittl, I found how to fix it, but did not find what the problem was. Basically, I added `--ignore-unmatch` to command `git rm` and it went smoothly!

Comment: @Gabrielius: that's already contained in my answer since 2012? :)

Comment: @knittl, yeah funny. The problem started when I removed `--ignore-unmatch` because with it nothing was deleted, but then this permissions error appeared. I then re-added the parameter, but used it with a *different path* this time. Thus the real issue was the wrong path :)

Comment: Deleting `.git/refs/original/` did not solve my issue. I restored the folder, then used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34177510/4080966) to remove the backup.

Comment: For file path with space in the name use this:
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch 'large file.pdf'" HEAD

Answer (score 33):

Use this command to remove original backup:

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

Here is gist I used to filter-branch my git repo:  https://gist.github.com/k06a/25a0214c98bc19fd6817

Comment: This is the right solution to remove the backup! Deleting `.git/refs/original/` does not solve the problem.

Comment: Be sure to change 'master' to the branch you are attempting to fix.. in my case 'develop'

Comment: `git show-ref | awk '/ refs.original.refs/{print$2}'` to find all the backups your repo has.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and the answer above didn't fix it.  There was no .git/refs/original/ directory left.  The solution for me was to delete the  .git/packed-refs file.

Comment: Same problem. No `.git/packed-refs` file, however, and no folder `original` in `.git/refs`. Anyone?

Comment: Resolved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746580/removing-history-from-git-git-command-fails) by adding the `-r` flag to command.

Comment: Same problem here. Deleting packed-refs solved the problem, but it also ruined the rest of my git directory, and I had to restore from backup.

Answer (score 2):

Add a force to the filter branch command.