# GitHub "Your Contributions" and private repositories

Tags: github

I'm working in a command which uses a private repository at GitHub. This is a contract work and once it's finished, I won't have access to this repository anymore.

I commit there quite often and, therefore my "Your Contributions" (GitHub's "timeline" or " Summary of Pull Requests, issues opened and commits") looks pretty good. I want it to remain look the same.

But nonetheless, when the job finishes and I won't have access to this repository (the admin restrict access for me to this repository), I'm almost sure my "timeline" will become more gray **immediately**, since this repository is deleted from the list of the repositories I can contribute to.

Isn't that so and how do I avoid this?

**UPDATE**:
The reason I want to avoid it is that I want the **potential employees** to be able to see how I work by looking at my timeline.

Comment: Are you trying to make it still look good for *them*, or continue to look good for you? My answer below is about letting them still see your contributions, but it will break it for you.

Comment: @Rophuine -- for me and for potential employees.

Answer (score 6):

Re-stating the problem briefly, once your account is removed as a contributor, your contributions don't show up in the same way they currently do. You want people staying on the project to still see your contributions as a model of how they should be committing.

Once you are finished, get them to create a dummy GitHub account for you. This account will remain a collaborator, but you won't be able to access it. You can then re-write the commit history to make it seem like the dummy account made all of your commits. The history will look the same, but you won't have access to the dummy account - or their repo.

There is plenty of good information on how to do this: see e.g. [Git, rewrite previous commit usernames and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919878/git-rewrite-previous-commit-usernames-and-emails) or you could try https://github.com/davidfokkema/git-rewrite-author

Comment: I didn't get, sorry. Can you make it clearer?

Comment: Yep, sure, I'll flesh it out a bit more. Gimme a minute.

Comment: Is that better? Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Here is the update -- "I want the **potential employees** to be able to see how I work by seeing my timeline"

Comment: Ah, you mean potential employers? Like people who might want to hire you? Sorry, I don't think I can help with that. You could take screen-shots and offer them in interviews? Or put them up on your blog?

Comment: Or use this utility I created for transcribing private repos into your GitHub account without exposing source code: https://github.com/ebrian/gitdummy