# Anonymise a Github repository

Tags: git, github

I've been working on a private repo (Github) with a few other people. The project is now done I want to fork it to my own Githhub profile and make it public to reference my experience from that project.

The other people on the team does not want this repo to be linked to them in any way, and has agreed to have it public on my profile as long as none of their Github user info or emails or anything like that is linked to the repo.

Is there a way to keep the commit-history and anonymise all the other users? The results should be that all the commits are still there, but the author of the teammates' commits is a generic user? 
Thanks.

edit1: I found this [Git, rewrite previous commit usernames and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919878/git-rewrite-previous-commit-usernames-and-emails) but unsure if the first answer there will work with Github.. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the described method if you first clone the project from the GitHub locally, make the edits, and push to a new repository on GitHub, without using the Fork action.