# Why "git log" show me path to The Bat instead of an email?

Tags: git, github

[image]

Even though user.mail = mymail@test.com

In the course githowto the log looks like:

```
commit 911e8c91caeab8d30ad16d56746cbd6eef72dc4c
Author: Alexander Shvets <alex@githowto.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 9 10:27:54 2011 -0500

First Commit
```

Comment: `user.email`, not `user.mail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for one commit, as illustrated in "[Change commit author at one specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/6309)", you need:

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

And of course, fix your setting:

```
git config --global user.email email@address.com
```

(email, not mail, as commented)

---

If you had more than one commit with the wrong email, you would need a [filter-branch as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768843/6309) after setting the proper email (`git config user.email`, as commented)

```
git change-commits GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL "new@email.com" HEAD~10..HEAD
```

(assuming here your last 10 commits are incorrect: adapt the number to your case)

Here, this is a simplified alias which forces the new value:

```
change-commits = "!f() { VAR=$1; NEW=$2; shift 2; git filter-branch --env-filter \"export $VAR='$NEW';" $@; }; f "
```

---

In both cases, if you have not pushed yet, that is OK: the amend or filter-branch will rewrite the existing commits, but you will still be able to do a regular push.

Comment: `git commit --amend --reset-author` should suffice, given that this is supposedly the first commit.

Comment: @jsageryd Right. I missed the "first commit" in the question. Let me edit the answer for you to cancel the downvote.

Comment: THANK YOU! It was about "user.mail" (instead of "user.email")