# Does GitHub consider .mailmap for contribution graph

Tags: github, mailmap

Have got a git repo with incorrect contributors and their contributions. Repo has few commit's from different emails and alias name and we have added `.mailmap` to resolve this issue.

Shortlog recognizes `.mailmap` and groups contributions accordingly, but it doesn't reflect on GitHub. Does GitHub consider `.mailmap` file or should we have to wait for GitHub re-run the graph.

```sh
git shortlog -sne
```

Note: We have waited for 24 hours already

Comment: [Yes, github consider .mailmap file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/mailmap.txt)

Comment: @Andreas yes git considers, and shortlog is the proof. Need to know about github considers as well ? The link points git repo that is hosted on github, so i am considering it as git documentation and not github's.

Comment: Did it ever start working for you? I'm curious if it works as well. I can find no evidence that it actually works.

Comment: @donatJ Yes, it worked for us.

Answer (score 6):

Github considers .mailmap file for contributions and it takes time to update contributors graph and pulse (in our case it was 24 - 36 hours )

Comment: I have not been able to get this working, despite waiting several days.  Are you willing to post a link to the repository where you got `.mailmap` to be reflected in the Contributors graph?

Comment: It was in a enterprise github installation with restricted access.

Comment: @MusicMan this [Github Community post](https://github.community/t/how-to-get-mailmap-to-work-and-record-contributions-in-relevant-users-profile/121285) from July 2020 says that "GitHub does not support using mailmap files" and "The only way to update the contributor details in your commits is to rewrite git history".  I just pushed up a .mailmap file to my Github Enterprise Server repo and will update here if my contribution graph is corrected.

Comment: In my case contribution graph was fixed. Not sure if this is a recent development / fix.

Comment: Hmm, strange.  It's been 4 days since pushing up the .mailmap and our Github Enterprise Server repo is still not showing a fixed contribution graph.

Comment: @raychz Did this ever end up working for you?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. The only thing that works for me is adding the email addresses of the commits that aren't recognized under `Settings/Emails`.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub currently (as of 2023-12-06) does **not** remap author names or email addresses according to the rules in a `.mailmap` file.

I've created a [small test repository](https://github.com/richardebeling/github-mailmap-test) that you can use to verify this.