# Git change user's credentials in past commits without changing the history (date of commits)

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I've started to work on some projects in the past without giving my correct GitHub email address in the credentials of git from Terminal. So every commit was showed as follows:

[image]

These commits are made without my user name so these commits are also not showing in the contributions section:

[image]

As it is shown in image 1 that I've made a commit on March 14 but it is not shown in the contributions (because of the wrong email was set for the git credentials). Now I all my latest contributions are shown correct but I also want all the old contributions of my past projects to be shown like this. But I don't want to change the history of commits (i.e. date).

Comment: Try git mailmap. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629125/does-github-consider-mailmap-for-contribution-graph. And doc on the `.mailmap` feature, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors.

Comment: Add your other email address to your GitHub profile.

Comment: @EdwardThomson yes I've added my correct email address for latest commits, but my question is for the previous commits that I made. Now my issue is resolved and I've posted the answer below here. Thanks

Comment: Right, I'm talking about the email address you used for the early commits.  You can have multiple email addresses in GitHub, and that will associate commits made with all of them to your profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `.mailmap` to write all the commits but I think this is a bit difficult solution.
The simpler solution that I found very useful is as follows:

--> First of all, use `git shortlog -sne` into your project directory to check all the users' commits with their emails.

Now, if your project has the only user that is used for commits, then you should try this:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "
 GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='newName'
 GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='newEmail'
 GIT_COMMITER_NAME='newName'
 GIT_COMMITER_EMAIL='newEmail'
" HEAD
```

`Remember:` If your project has multiple contributors, it'll also update that to just one contributor that you will provide.

--> For multiple contributors, where you want to update one or specific contributor. You can try the conditional approach, e.g.

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "
if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = 'currentWrongEmail'
then
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='newEmail'
fi
if test "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = 'currentWrongEmail'
then
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='newEmail'
fi
" HEAD
```

At the end of both cases, use `git push -f` to update the remote repository instantly.