# git - how to fix previous commit user email?

Tags: git

I'm trying to push some changes, but my company's bitbucket server is stopping me (rightfully so!) to commit with the wrong committer email. `git push` fails with five entries like the one I put bellow:

```
remote: Push rejected.
remote:
remote: refs/heads/feature/<branch>: efc45b4345f500b0175624d97a3cad96d9268e61: expected committer email '<company@email>' but found '<some@value>'
```

How can I change the committer email for the commits I need to push?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git, rewrite previous commit usernames and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919878/git-rewrite-previous-commit-usernames-and-emails)

Comment: I had seen that one, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: What about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-to-change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-gi)

Answer (score 0):

```
git commit --amend --author="Author Name <email@address.com>"
```

Comment: This seems to work for the last commit, but can I cherry pick an older one and do the same?

Comment: You can do an interactive rebase and modify the desired commit in the described way. See [Rewriting History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Comment: you can also rewrite the author of last 10 commits using 
```git change-commits GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL "old@email.com" "new@email.com" HEAD~10..HEAD```