# Is there a way to change email id for already commited stuff on github?

Tags: git, email, bitbucket, push, commit

I have been using GitHub and Bitbucket for different repositories.
For my Github repo, I realized later that I have been using bitbucket email to commit and push on to Github.
I am not sure if it is possible to change those already pushed commits to my email?
I already changed email back on GitHub to make sure my future commits and pushes go from the email I want. Oh I also connected Bitbucket to my GitHub.

Comment: You would have to rewrite all of those older commits, which might not really be an option for you if the remote branch has already been published.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to:

- rewrite your local commits with the right email (see "[Git, rewrite previous commit usernames and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768843/6309)")
  See also the official GitHub page "[Changing author info](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info)".
- force push (`git push --force`) that rewritten branch to your GitHub repository (which can be problematic for other contributors: make sure to notify them)

The connection part is different, and depends on the protocol your are using for accessing your BitBucket repository (HTTPS or SSH)