# Changing git author info on all commits worked on one of my repos but not the others, why?

Tags: git, github, sublimemerge

I have various private [GitHub](https://github.com/) repos and use [Sublime Merge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/) to manage my commits.

I want to **change all the previous commit author details**:

From Name: This, Email: this@domain.com

To: Name: That, Email: that@domain.com

I have therefore followed [these instructions](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info) from GitHub and amended the code to the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch -f --env-filter '

CORRECT_NAME="That"
CORRECT_EMAIL="that@domain.com"

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"

' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

On one of the repos this worked and before I used `git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'` from the instrucitons Sublime Merge showed the potential changes and after running the push all the commits were now updated to the desired details.

All good, so I thought, until I tried this with several of my other repositories and no change shows in sublime and the push does nothing. I have no idea why there is a difference. The other repositories are similar in the fact they all have the same original committer.

Why does this not work for the other repos and how can I fix to allow me to do the changes?

Comment: How exactly are you running this script (for example, what is the working directory, what command do you use to run it)? What was the output for the one repository where it worked? Was the output different for the other repositories? Were there any error messages?

Comment: Do the other repositories have the same *author and committer* as the one were the script worked, or *only the same author*, or *only the same committer* (you say "same commiter" in the question text, but the script changes the author)?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it appears I was missing both AUTHOR and COMMITTER data, see my answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A better option would be to use the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).
See its [user manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html).

> To modify username and emails of commits, you can create a mailmap file in the format accepted by `git-shortlog`.
>   For example, if you have a file named my-mailmap you can run
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --mailmap my-mailmap
> ```
>
> and if the current contents of that file are as follows (if the specified mailmap file is version controlled, historical versions of the file are ignored):

```
Correct Name <correct@email.com> <old@email.com>
```

> then we can update username and/or emails based on the specified mapping.

See [`git shortlog` "mapping author" section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors) for the exact syntax of a mailmap file.

Or, with [callbacks](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#CALLBACKS):

```
git-filter-repo --name-callback 'return name.replace(b"OldName", b"NewName")' \
   --email-callback 'return email.replace(b"old@email.com", b"new@email.com")'
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, I've already changed the author details on my repos using the old method I posted but I will give this a try soon on a test repo, seems like an easier way for future.

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out looks I wasn't including both `AUTHOR` and `COMMITTER` details:

In terminal within repo directory:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='New Name'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='new@email.com'; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='New Name'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='new@email.com';" HEAD
```

Then:

```
git push --force --tags origin 'refs/heads/*'
```