# Push to GitHub mistakenly done by another GitHub account

Tags: git, github

I had a local repository named `a` which had been already associated with a remote repository named `A` of GitHub account `A-github`,
and I also had a local repository named `b` which had not been associated with any remote repository yet.

I created a new remote repository named `B` of GitHub account `B-github`, and I tried to do the first push to `B` from local repository `b`.

### What happened

- The push succeeded and I saw the page of `B` reflected the commits of `b`.
- However, the name of the user who had done the first push displayed on the page of `B` was not the name of `b`, but the name of the other GitHub account `A-github`.(The icon image was also the same as set in `A-github` page)
- And when I clicked the name of the user who first pushed ( `A-github`), I went to the page of `A-github` account.
- What is weird is that this happening is **not** recorded on `Contribution activity` on the Overview page of `A-github`.

### My guess

I'm guessing this was the problem of `git config` of the local repository `b`. I tried `git config -l` and found that `user.name` and `user.email` were doubled like this:

```
...
...
user.name = the user name I use for repository `a` and `A`
user.email = the user email I use for repository `a` and `A`
...
...
user.name = the user name I use for repository `b` and `B`
user.email = the user email I use for repository `b` and `B`
...
...
...
```

I want to let git use a right user (`b`) to do push to `B` and if I can, I want to cancel the push done by `A-github`

What should I do?

### Progress

I've installed `git filter-repo` via package manager and tried the method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590204/changing-git-author-info-on-all-commits-worked-on-one-of-my-repos-but-not-the-ot/59591928#59591928),

using `git filter-repo --mailmap my-mailmap` with the text file formatted as

```
Correct Name <correct@email.com> <old@email.com>
```

Then, I pressed enter.
However, the result is the shell just returned

```
Python
```

and it seems nothing happened.
I think I need some more trials.

### Am I doing right?

I'm a bit afraid that I'm using `git filter-repo` correctly.

My comprehension is that I firstly need to create a text file named as formatted below:

```
Correct Name <correct@email.com> <old@email.com>
```

where `Correct Name` and `<correct@email.com>` is the name and email with which I want to replace the ones of present author and committer already written in the commit log, `<old@email.com>` is the present email written in log.

I'm entering email with putting `<>` on both ends.

Is this ok?

### Progress 2

I found that it seemed I needed Python installed in advance on my PC to use `git-filter-repo` command, so I installed Python via Scoop a while ago.
I tried again implementing the command above, and　this time the shell returned:

```
Cannot read my-mailmap
```

Another difficulty came.

Now that the discussion is going off this topic,[I posted a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66634193/git-filter-repo-doesnt-read-my-mailmap-file) and I would close this question. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes `<>` is correct. You can see an example in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors (except, in your case, you need to include the new *and old* emails)

Comment: Thank you. I would like to some of the snippets shown that link. Now that the discussion is going off the first topic of this question, [I posted a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66634193/git-filter-repo-doesnt-read-my-mailmap-file) and I would close this question. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do a `git config -l --show-scope --show-origin` in your repository: that way, you will be sure to see what is a local config, which overrides a global config.

Second, you can use [`git filter-repo` to change the user.name/email of your commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59591928/6309) in repoB: yo will then need to `git push --force` it (which is not a big issue if you are alone working on that new repository).

Comment: Thank you. I tried git filter-repo as shown at the link, but it seems the command did not run properly. (Please see my new edit of this question above.)

Comment: @somia Can you try the same command on a fresh cloned copy of your repository?

Comment: I created a new cloned repository and tried the same command, but the result is the same. Just returning `Python`.

Comment: @somia Did you install it as in https://superuser.com/a/1589985/141?

Comment: No. I installed Scoop (package manager for Windows) first and then installed git filter-repo with the command `scoop install git filter-repo` .(which was recommended way for windows to install git filter-repo)  But I was a bit afraid that git filter-repo may not be installed correctly because I got a kind of warning while installing it. I'm thinking I should try another way as the link you cited.

Comment: I think I should post a new question about this. I would post new one and  add the link. Thank you for recommending me `git-filter-repo`.