# git-filter-repo doesn't read my mailmap file

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch, git-filter-repo, mailmap

Continued to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614236/push-to-github-mistakenly-done-by-another-github-account/66614340?noredirect=1#comment117789980_66614340), I need to use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) in order to [modify the Author name and Comitter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58263216/how-to-change-commit-author-for-multiple-commits-using-filter-branch) of some of the commits recorded in my repository's log .But I have some troubles about this.

### The problem

I have a file named `my-mailmap` in the directory of my local repository, which is formatted

```
CorrectName <correct@email.com> <old@email.com>
```

- `CorrectName` is the new name with which I want to replace the name recorded in log
- `correct@email.com` is the new email with which I want to replace the old email recorded in log
- `old@email.com` is the old email recorded in log

Then, I opened cmd and implemented the command:

```
git filter-repo --mailmap my-mailmap
```

And the result is

```
Cannot read my-mailmap
```

What is happening? I couldn't find any report of this error message.

Maybe I have some mistakes in syntax of [mailmap](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors) and I'm trying to find them.
I would appreciate if you give me any information.

### Other informations

I installed `Python` and `git-filter-repo` using Scoop as shown [here](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) in my Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem on my own.

The problem was that I was just working on a wrong directory which has no `my-mailmap` file.

I was confused with re-creating a couple of clone copies of the repository for trial and error.
After I changed the correct directory and tried the command again, it succeeded.

I'm sorry.

Comment: I was about to say that: look at the source: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/aaf1c3375210a9e256ff99b7b340ca7ecac6f72b/git-filter-repo#L285-L286. It means the file is not readable/accessible.

Comment: I'm sorry. The problem was solved and it was just my stupid mistake. But I'm sure your advice to look into the manual of `git-filter-repo` would help me a lot using it. Thank you for taking time for my question.

Comment: I have the same issue, I did see in the source that the system can't find it (`if not os.access(filename, os.R_OK):
      raise SystemExit(_("Cannot read %s") % decode(filename))`), but I still cannot figure out what's wrong. I'm in a freshly cloned repo, have the .mailmap file in the root of that repo, where I am as well, and it still can't read it. Tried with sudo, changing the access rights on .mailmap, changing the file name, trying with just "--use-mailmap" - no luck. Interesting, when going with "--use-mailmap", it also gives a trace of an error, but still fails in the same line.