# Remove Old Email from GitHub API Page

Tags: github, github-api

**Question:** how to remove my email from a [GitHub API page](https://api.github.com)?

**Intro:** I've made some changes to my project on GitHub (started using GitHub recently, thus, not quite familiar with it). Then, I've changed my email in my User Settings. But my old email address is still shown on the API page.

[image: API page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's referring to the email in your commits.  When you make a commit, the name and email of the author and committer (which are usually the same) are embedded in the commit.  Typically these are specified with the `user.name` and `user.email` options.  Note that `user.name` is a personal name, not a username.

If you want to change the email you're using, then you can set it with `git config --global user.email NEW-EMAIL`.  That will change things going forward, but if you want to rewrite old commits, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919878/git-rewrite-previous-commit-usernames-and-emails).

Comment: bk2204, thank you for your answer. I want rewrite old commits, however, `git: 'change-commits' is not a git command.`

Comment: That answer specifies to create an alias to implement that command.