# Github Contributions do not show

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I push my commits by git bash (Windows11) everyday, but they are not show as contribution on my github.

I've read several artilces like [this](https://dev.to/duhbhavesh/why-my-commits-aren-t-showing-up-on-github-contributions-graph-3a2h). I've checked my email address and it is already added in git.

I have no idea what is the problem, and I really hope my commits in the past days can show as conribution.

Hope anyone can help. Thank you very much!

My repository is https://github.com/frankychhoa/codeeveryday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your commits are made by `[frankychhoa] <[frankychhoa@gmail.com]>` which is not normal syntax.

You probably just need to set your name and e-mail address correctly in your client (fix the actual name, I'm just guessing):

```
git config --global user.name "Franky Chhoa"
git config --global user.email "frankychhoa@gmail.com"
```

Running `git log` in your repo shows:

```
commit c961e52fe6 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: [frankychhoa] <[frankychhoa@gmail.com]>
Date:   Wed Sep 28 21:58:11 2022 +0900

    2022.09.28

...
```

But it's supposed to look like:

```
commit c961e52fe6 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Franky Chhoa <frankychhoa@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 28 21:58:11 2022 +0900

    2022.09.28

...
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

After changing my user name, now my commit can show as contribution sucessfully.
However, I would like to ask if it is possible to make my past commits show as contributions.
Thank you for your kindness!

Comment: You can use `git filter-branch` for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2931914/3216427 Basically, you have to rewrite the whole history and change the author on each commit, one commit at a time. Fortunately, there are tools to automate that!

Answer (score 0):

To push data using git bash follow the steps

open your project folder

right click and open gitbash

then follow the steps

```
git init
git status
git add .
git commit -m "uploading"
```

still you are in your local directory but wait before uploading check if you are connected to the remote reposetry or not

master/ main

```
git remote get-url origin
git remote get-url master
```

if you found not remote url then you can set it

```
git remote set-url origin <newurl>)
```

then follow the below steps to
check you remote repostry is it main /orign

```
git push -u orign master
git push -u origin main
```