# How to revert changes to git commit usernames and emails?

Tags: git, github

I was planning to change some commits' usernames and emails in `git log`. Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2920001/8926191), it changes all commits' username and emails, while I only want to modify certain commits. I am wondering how can I revert this change?

Comment: Can you detail certain commits ? Are we speaking about a couple or a long list ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+filter-branch

Answer (score 1):

`git filter-branch` has helpfully made a backup of the references that it has rewritten in the `refs/original` hierarchy.

Say, you have a branch `main` (that `HEAD` was pointing to before the operation). The full name is actually `refs/heads/main`. You will now find the backup under `refs/original/refs/heads/main`. To undo the branch you can simply do this:

```
git branch -f main refs/original/refs/heads/main
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only ran `git filter-branch` once on your branch, you can reset it to its original head:

```
git reset refs/original/refs/heads/<branchname>
```